# Sorting variable list of file names by size

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting

I'm trying to create a little script that will take file names then sort that list by size and doing command over that list. So far I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
filenames="one \
           two \
           three"
for i in $filenames; do
...
done
```

It works but I would like to sort the list by filesize before it hits the for command.

Comment: Similar (though for `zsh` instead of `bash` and for `mtime` instead of `size`): [How to sort a zsh array by modification date?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/578522)

Answer (score 2):

If your filenames don't contain any newlines and your system has GNU `stat`, you could:

- Use an array variable `filenames`
- Use `stat` to print the size and filename of each file, then use `sort` on the result (reverse numeric) and
  then remove the first field (the size) with `cut` to get the filenames ordered by size (largest first).
- Feed the result to a `while` loop for further processing.

```
filenames=( one two three )
while IFS= read -r file; do
  echo "do something with $file"
done < <(stat --printf '%s\t%n\n' -- "${filenames[@]}" | sort -nr | cut -f2-)
```

---

The same as above, but using the null character as delimiter (if you can't guarantee your filenames won't contain newlines; you'll also need GNU `sort` and GNU `cut`):

```
filenames=( one two three )
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
  printf 'do something with %s\n' "$file"
done < <(stat --printf '%s\t%n\0' -- "${filenames[@]}" | sort -znr | cut -zf2-)
```

Note that for filenames of type *symlink*, it's the size of the link itself (as opposed to that of the file it points to) that is considered. Add the `-L` option to `stat` to change that.

Note that it won't work for a file called `-` as `stat` interprets it as meaning the file open on stdin. Use `./-` instead to work around it.

Comment: That works perfect, thanks! Can I ask a couple of questions though, is < < at the end done just saying to the loop to expect input from the following? I've never seen that before. Would changing the filename variable to a read break anything so I can just pipe the new filenames to it instead of changing that variable Everytime?

Comment: Yes, `<` is a input redirection and `<(...)` is a process substitution and behaves as if the list of commands inside it were a file. You can replace `"${filenames[@]}"` with a list of your filenames if you don't want to use an array.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`, same method as in [that answer to a similar question about sorting by mtime](/a/578889), itself adapted from [that one](/a/482492), to sort arrays based on arbitrary orders (see that latter one for details):

```
zmodload zsh/stat

array=(one two three...)

# store sizes in an "A"ssociative array:
typeset -A size
stat -nL -A size +size -- $array

# sort using the oe glob qualifier "n"umerically
sorted_array=(/(e['reply=($array)']noe['REPLY=$size[$REPLY]'])
```